# Convert .cs to .dll

Tags: c#, dll

How can I compile a .cs file into a DLL?

My project name is WA. In my `bin` folder after the compilation, I found:

- `WA.exe`
- `WA.vshost.exe`
- `WA.pdb`

Comment: In project properties, change the output type of your project to CLASS LIBRARY instead of Console Application/Windows Application.

Comment: Thank u Joe. I got an instruction from my reporting manager that i want to use pssnapin program. can u guide me, plz..

Answer (score 16):

You have to compile it:

```
csc /t:library source.cs  -> source.dll
```

Comment: It is the C# compiler. Follow the link provided below.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using Visual Studio?

If you create a Class Library project in VS, add your .cs file and then compile the project, the output will be a .dll file.

Answer (score 4):

You use a compiler. Csc.exe comes with the .NET Framework.

Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx

You can also use an IDE like Visual Studio if you want the development process to be easier.

Answer (score 1):

Its automatically created for you when you run a build in visual studio. Check the bin folder in your project folder.

Comment: When all I do is click build in visual studio I would say it is automatic for me

Answer (score 0):

For your information there are two kinds of DLL file which named "Managed" and "Un-Managed". Managed type is which you can use and add to your references in Visual Studio IDE. 
However, if you want to convert each classes separately to Dll, you can use new windows application-> class library. After debugging and running that you can find DLL file in your source destination. Try it.
P.S: Usually you forced to use more than one class in one DLL file.